# How to remove duplicate columns with the same values from a data frame

Tags: r, sas

I've got a data frame like this one:

```
1    1    1    a    1    a    
2    1    2    b    1    b    
3    8    3    b    1    b    
4    8    4    k    1    k    
1    1    1    t    1    t    
2    1    2    t    1    t
```

I want to remove the duplicate columns with the same value , i.e column 3 is duplicate of column 1 so i want to remove either one column 3 or column 1, and column 6 is duplicate of column 4 so i want to remove either one column 6 or column 4. I have very big data with 800 columns with columns name like a1,a2,a3....a800.

so my result will be like this

```
1    1    a    1       
2    1    b    1        
3    8    b    1       
4    8    k    1    
1    1    t    1   
2    1    t    1
```

It would be great if anyone help me on this task.

Thanks for all your reply. I will try these codes and it would be great if i get any equivalent in SAS and R.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one of these would work for you:

#### Create a logical vector identifying the duplicated columns.

I would *guess* that the `paste` approach would probably be faster..., but `duplicated` on the transposed `data.frame` might be more reliable....

```
Dups1 <- duplicated(lapply(mydf, paste, collapse = ""))
Dups2 <- duplicated(t(mydf))

Dups1
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Dups2
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### Use either of those logical vectors to grab the columns you want.

```
mydf[!Dups1]
  V1 V2 V4 V5
1  1  1  a  1
2  2  1  b  1
3  3  8  b  1
4  4  8  k  1
5  1  1  t  1
6  2  1  t  1
```

Comment: +1, though paste introduces issues with frame shifts in your columns (i.e. consider rows a, bc vs. ab, c) and the nightmare of dealing with non-occurring separators.  I guess if it's just numbers and factors then you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. I will try these codes and it would be great if i get any equivalent in SAS

Comment: @user3313787, Sven's answer is ***way*** more efficient and reliable if you're going with R.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
dat[!duplicated(unclass(dat))]

#   V1 V2 V4 V5
# 1  1  1  a  1
# 2  2  1  b  1
# 3  3  8  b  1
# 4  4  8  k  1
# 5  1  1  t  1
# 6  2  1  t  1
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The SAS code below should give you the desired answer. The algo is simple: expelling the non-duplicate pairs of columns from each row of the original data. And the major techniques I used are:

(1) exploiting `set` option `point=  nobs=` to perform random access on the original data set

(2) process character/numeric variables separately due to constraints on SAS array

(3) use `call symputx()` in `data _NULL_` to store data set properties into macro variables

```
/* original dataset */
*only x1,x2,x4,x5 are non-duplicate;
data a; 
    input x1 x2 x3 x4 $ x5 x6 $ x7 x8 $;
    cards;
1    1    1    a    1    a    1    a
2    1    2    b    1    b    2    b
3    8    3    b    1    b    3    b
4    8    4    k    1    k    4    k
1    1    1    t    1    t    1    t
2    1    2    t    1    t    2    t
;run;

/* get the number of columns (character/numeric, respectively) */
data _NULL_;
    set a(firstobs=1 obs=1);
    /* # of numeric vars */
    array arrN{*} _Numeric_;
    x=dim(arrN);
    call symputx("NN",x,"G");

    /* # of char vars */
    array arrC{*} _Character_;
    y=dim(arrC);
    call symputx("NC",y,"G");

    /* #obs of the input dataset */
    dsid=open("a");
    z=attrn(dsid,"NOBS");
    call symputx("N",z,"G");
    w=close(dsid);

    /* check */
    %put NN=&NN, NC=&NC, N=&N;
run;

/* create lists of possible duplicated pairs */
* numeric variables;
data dup_n;
    do i=1 to &NN;
        do j=i+1 to &NN;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

* character variables;
data dup_c;
    do i=1 to &NC;
        do j=i+1 to &NC;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

/* eliminate possible dup pairs */
* read the original data set, one row at a time, and eliminate 
* non-duplicate pairs from the possible list;

%macro random_access;
%do pt=1 %to &N;
    data dup_N2(keep=i j) dup_C2(keep=i j);
        /* read row &pt from the original dataset */
        set a(firstobs=&pt obs=&pt);

        /* process numeric variables */
        array arrN{*} _Numeric_;
        do k1=1 to N1;
            set dup_N point=k1 NOBS=N1;
            if arrN{i}=arrN{j} then output dup_N2;
        end;

        /* process character variables */
        array arrC{*} _character_;
        do k2=1 to N2;
            set dup_C point=k2 NOBS=N2;
            if arrC{i}=arrC{j} then output dup_C2;
        end;
    run;

    /* renew duplicate pairs */
    proc datasets lib=work nolist;
        delete dup_N dup_C;
        change dup_N2=dup_N dup_C2=dup_C; /*rename datasets*/
    quit;
%end;
%mend;
%random_access;
* kill the macro after use;
%SYSMACDELETE random_access /nowarn; 


/* pick the duplicated rows */
* note: the first number of the duplicates will not appear in column j;
proc sort data=dup_N(drop=i) nodupkey;
    by j;
run;

proc sort data=dup_C(drop=i) nodupkey;
    by j;
run;

/* concatenate the names of duplicate variables */
data _NULL_;
    set a;
    array arrN{*} _Numeric_;
    array arrC{*} _character_;
    format dropN dropC $32767.;
    do k1=1 to N1;
        set dup_N(rename=(j=j1)) point=k1 NOBS=N1;
        dropN=catx(' ',dropN,vname(arrN{j1}));
        put dropN=; *check;
    end;
    do k2=1 to N2;
        set dup_C(rename=(j=j2)) point=k2 NOBS=N2;
        dropC=catx(' ',dropC,vname(arrC{j2}));
        put dropC=; *check;
    end;

    str=catx(' ',dropN,dropC);
    call symputx("dropAll",str,"G");
    stop;
run;
%put dropAll=&dropAll; *check;

/* output answer */
data answer(drop=&dropAll);
    set a;
run;

*cleanup;
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    delete dup_:;
quit;
```

My code may not do the best. Just showing that it is possible.

Best regards,

Bill